# what's z-index and what is it used for?

Tags: css, z-index

I'm learning web design. I don't know **z-index** and **what is it used for**...
I'm trying to positioning a drop down menu. I read it can be useful for menu  in a book.
so I'll be thankful if someone answer me.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/ this should be helpful

Comment: you can think of z-index property like the tool that move layers forward or backwards in illustrator

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the docs:

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of an element and its
>   descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one
>   covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an
>   element with a lower one.
>
> For a positioned box, the **z-index** property specifies:
>
> - The stack level of the box in the current [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).
> - List item Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

Example:

```css
.dashed-box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: dashed;
  height: 8em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
.gold-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 3;
  /* put .gold-box above .green-box and .dashed-box */
  background: gold;
  width: 80%;
  left: 60px;
  top: 3em;
}
.green-box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  /* put .green-box above .dashed-box */
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20%;
  left: 20em;
  top: -25px;
  height: 7em;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashed-box">Dashed box
  <span class="gold-box">Gold box</span>
  <span class="green-box">Green box</span>
</div>
```

[z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)